# How to kill zombie python thread in google colab?

Tags: python, multithreading, google-colaboratory

I have created threads in python using `threading` library in `Google Colab`. I want to eliminate the zombie threads which don't have any use. Suppose, I created 20 threads and then had no need for them and I wanted to create new meaningful threads, naturally, they won't start until the zombie threads finish processing. I have been trying the ways to kill threads from [this website](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-different-ways-to-kill-a-thread/) but some of them work on google colab, most don't. I can't use multiprocessing library because it interferes with my program. Threading library is working fine but I just want to avoid the scenario that I mentioned in the beginning.
The following is the code for thread Class:

```
class myThread(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self, threadID, func):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.threadID = threadID
    self.func = func

  def run(self):
    self.result=self.func()

  def join(self):
    threading.Thread.join(self)
    return self.result
```

I need to kill the threads that I create like

```
t1=myThread(1,another_func)
if want_to_kill:
  t1.kill()
```

**I specifically want this to work on Google Colab**

Comment: Call `.join()` on them?

Comment: yeah but join will only work after every thread is finished running. It doesn't terminate any running thread. Rather it makes them wait for the remaining unfinished threads.

Comment: Use a [condition](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Condition) variable

Comment: How? Can you please elaborate by writing a code for the given myThread class which works in google colab? There are many things that I have tried which work on my local setup but don't work in google colab.